# What is official nomenclature for the words preceded by backslashes and the words inside of curly braces

Tags: terminology

When using **LaTeX** ...

- I usually refer to the `\begin` inside of `\begin{Bmatrix}` as a "command"
- I usually refer to the `Bmatrix` inside `\begin{Bmatrix}` as a "command argument"

What is the official nomenclature in the **TeX** and/or **LaTeX** communities for the strings preceded by a backslash, such as `\begin` and the strings inside of curly braces such as `Bmatrix`.

I usually say that some **TeX** commands accept arguments and other **TeX** commands do not accept arguments, but that nomenclature might be non-standard within the community.

> The `\begin` and `\frac` commands both accept arguments, but the commands `\times`, `\div`, `\pm`, and `\mp` are all examples of commands which accept no input arguments.

Comment: Knuth calls the items beginning with backslashes "control sequences", but "commands" is more common with LaTeX.  The material enclosed in braces after a command is an "argument".  Whether or not a command requires or accepts one or more arguments, it's still a "command"; no name distinction is made.  The `\begin{...} ... \end{...}` construction defines an "environment" known by the name used as the argument to `\begin`,

Comment: Also the term "macro" is regularly used as a synonym of "command", due to LaTeX being a macro expansion language (https://tex.stackexchange.com/search?q=macro gives 42 thousand results currently).

Comment: @Marijn it is regularly used but makes me unhappy:-) (`\begin` is a macro but `\times` is not, for example)

Comment: Is `\count0` a register, or is `\count` a command and 0 an argument?  Obviously the TikZ `\p`, `\x` and `\y` registers are emulated.